# How to create custom blend mode in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, glsl, shader, blending

I'd like to use a custom blend mode (linear burn) to blend the `SKSpriteNodes` of my `SKScene` however the only options available are `Add`, `Subtract`, `Multiply`, `MultiplyX2`, `Screen`, and `Replace`.

Is there any way to set a custom blend mode?
Can I blend all my sprites using a shader? If so, how?

Comment: Generally, GLSL shaders in iOS can use [Programmable Blending](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW23). You can associate a shader with any sprite using `SKShader`. I don't know if `SKShader` actually exposes programmable blending, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just talked to a SpriteKit engineer on the 2016's WWDC SpriteKit lab and it is not currently possible to use custom blend modes in SpriteKit.